# Elance / UpWork proflie pages on resume?

Tags: interviewing, resume, applications, freelancing

I've built up a decent profile and work history as a freelance software developer on both Elance and now UpWork. Indeed, the client reviews alone trump anything I could possibly boast about myself, and my profile is doing a much better job of selling me than my resume ever could.

I an now applying to full-time and non-freelance jobs, and I want to ensure that recruiters (particularly the ultimate decision-makers) see these profiles at some point during the recruitment process.

What's the best / most subtle way to do this? I've created shortened URLs to my profile pages (e.g. http://bit.ly/MyUsername-Elance), and put them at the top of my resume. But based on what I've read, most people are advising against this. And of course on a printed resume, the URLs serve no function.

If I chose not to link to these profiles on my resume, how best to bring them up?

Comment: Most font career (15 years) has been sprint in regular appointment. It's only in the 6 six months that I've gone self-employed.

Comment: Android auto-completion playing havoc. You get the drift through.

Comment: As someone not familiar with Elance, are user names unique and searchable? For example, could you say "@Pyderman on Elance" and be findable? You could also embed a hyperlink over the text for your digital resumes.

Comment: @DavidK On Elance, it's a neat enough URL e.g elance.com/MyUsername. UpWork though, it's an ugly, longwinded URL containing a trailing 16-character string. Hence my shortening of both.

Comment: @Pyderman, my point was whether you can direct people to your profile *without* using a URL of any sort, if you are able to concisely provide enough information to allow someone to search for your profile. You could also include links to these profiles on LinkedIn, as that is a website they are almost guaranteed to check.

Answer (score 6):

Resumes are more for listing out your relevant experience and qualifications, not as a list of endorsements. You should definitely put what you've freelanced on your resume, but your profiles and client feedback might be better suited for your cover letter and/or as an interview topic. However, I think it may be appropriate to have a link to your profile if you're interviewing for maybe some consulting firm that might normally deal with this kind of stuff, in which case your experience as a freelancer would be relevant *per se*.

Comment: Welcome to the site @aaaa, thanks for submitting a good first answer. +1

Comment: The company is a bricks-and-mortar company, and not a consultancy. The *role itself* though is a remote one, if this has any bearing on your view?

Answer (score 2):

> What's the best / most subtle way to do this? I've created shortened
>   URLs to my profile pages (e.g. http://bit.ly/MyUsername-Elance), and
>   put them at the top of my resume. But based on what I've read, most
>   people are advising against this. And of course on a printed resume,
>   the URLs serve no function.

Never put a shortened URL on your resume - always use the full URL. Some folks don't trust a shortened URL, and want to see where they are going before clicking.

> If I chose not to link to these profiles on my resume, how best to
>   bring them up?

Your experience as a freelancer should be part of your resume.

Depending on how many projects you participated in, can help determine if you list them all, or just summarize the overall experience.

For example, if you have a handful of significant projects lasting more than a month each, it would make sense to list them individually, and describe the project and your work.

On the other hand if you have dozens of short-term projects each lasting just a few week, then create one entry summarizing them all.

In addition you should refer to your freelance experience in your cover letter, and show how that experience applies directly to the full-time job you are applying for. This is the vehicle where you can highlight the kinds of terrific feedback you earned on UpWork.

Be prepared to discuss your experiences during the interviews, and be prepared to indicate how you think your freelance work will be different from the full-time work in the job for which you are applying.

Be aware that some hiring managers won't apply the same weight to freelance (particularly, at-home freelance) work, as they would to on-site, full-time work.

Comment: I believe the OP meant a redirect page has been created through the bit.ly site: so the URL is valid even if printed.  Typing it in will go to the redirect site and then to the intended page.

Comment: @Lyrl you are correct.

Comment: I get that people are sometimes suspicious of shortened URLs. But are people really going to be suspicious of a shortened URL created by a professional, experienced, intelligent real human who's crafted an otherwise stellar resume?

Comment: Slightly off-topic but related then: What about an about.me page containing nothing other than the two full freelance URLs. One downside I see is that seeing an about.me URL does not directly suggest to the reader than when they click though, there going to find my freelance profile links. Indeed, for all they know, they could be clicking through to hear about my dog's latest escapades or what I had for dinner.